# Bootstrap nested inner table with colspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For this Bootstrap styled table, I want the three columns (Sub1, Sub2, Sub3) widths to grow and align with their corresponding columns in the nested table.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesholcomb/r55Zc/

Comment: Your markup is incorrect [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Zc/1/)

Comment: **UPDATE:  This is a simplified example.  Yes, I know I can use rowspans to simplify and remedy, but if it can be done, I'd like to see a solution using inner tables.**

Comment: No you can't do it as simple as that...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a nested `<table>`, simply use the `rowspan` attribute on the first column. Borders (and some padding) can be removed with some creative CSS ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Zc/24/)):

### CSS

```css
th { text-align: center; }

tbody td {
    border-width: 0 !important;
    padding-top:0 !important;
}

tbody tr th ~ td {
    border-top-width: 1px !important;
    padding-top:8px !important;
}

tbody tr td:first-of-type {
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span*">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="3">Col1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Sub1</th>
                    <th>Sub2</th>
                    <th>Sub3</th>
                </tr>    
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="3">Row1</th>
                    <td>[-01234543333545]</td>
                    <td>[4567]</td>
                    <td>[1]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>[1]</td>
                    <td>[456.789]</td>
                    <td>[2]</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>[0]</td>
                    <td>[1]</td>
                    <td>[0000789.0123]</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This causes the row highlight to not work as I assume he wants it to work.

Comment: I realize I could get rid of the inner table and use rowspans much easier.  However, this is a simplified example. The actual implementation is using knockout.js for binding.  It's basically a giant pivot that contains inner tables along both dimensions that are sorted and grow and shrink independent of one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire row to highlight correctly, I suggest you tweak your table as others have suggested. However, instead of creating multiple trs and giving the td a rowspan of 3 (which causes row highlighting problems), just list the data in the td as an unordered list and make some adjustments to the css.

Table:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span*">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="3">Col1</th>
    </tr>    
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Sub1</td>
        <td>Sub2</td>
        <td>Sub3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Row1</td>
        <td><ul><li>[-01234543333545]</li><li>[1]</li><li>[0]</li></ul></td>
        <td><ul><li>[4567]</li><li>[456.789]</li><li>[1]</li></ul></td>
        <td><ul><li>[1]</li><li>[2]</li><li>[0000789.0123]</li></ul></td>      

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
td > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;        
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Zc/23/) forked from @Mr.Alien's suggestions.